# who in cakephp run custom query and retrieve result as list

Tags: mysql, cakephp

i run custom query in cake php 2.6.
but i want that result similar ***list***

> $sql = "SELECT Visit.id   FROM Visit ";
>
> $result = $this->Visit->query($sql);

the result is:

array
  0 =>

```
array

  'Visit' => 

    array

      'id' => string '221403' (length=6)
```

1 =>

```
array

  'Visit' => 

    array

      'id' => string '221402' (length=6)
```

2 =>

```
array

  'Visit' => 

    array

      'id' => string '221397' (length=6)
```

3 =>

```
array

  'Visit' => 

    array

      'id' => string '221394' (length=6)
```

4 =>

```
array

  'Visit' => 

    array

      'id' => string '221393' (length=6)
```

---

**I want result be:**

array
  0 =>

```
'id' => string '221403' (length=6)
```

1 =>

```
'id' => string '221402' (length=6)
```

2 =>

```
'id' => string '221397' (length=6)
```

3 =>

```
'id' => string '221394' (length=6)
```

4 =>

```
'id' => string '221393' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why custom query?

Instead of use custom query, you can simple use:

```
$visits = $this->Visit->find('all',array('fields' => array('Visit.id')));
$this->set('visits',$visits);
```